# Operating on a string rather than a selector from a jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I want to create a plugin that works like so:

```
var fmatted = $('someString').myFunction();
```

I've developed jQuery functions in the following manner:

```
$(someSelector).someFunction();
```

I know that the selector gets converted to a jQuery object and can be used via `this` in the plugin. However, if I want to use a string rather than a selector, I'm not sure how I can access that string within my plugin.

Basically, I want to be able to use a plugin to operate on something other than a selector, very much like jQuery's `.trim()` function, but I can't figure out how to access that within the plugin.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid use case for a jquery plugin.  The standard JQ object is nice because it always returns an object you can conduct more JQ operations on.  It doesn't make sense to have a JQ function here- you could 'extend string' somehow, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: @RSG - I get your point and I totally agree. I didn't realize that their was a _better_ approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `selector` property:

```
var jQueryObject = $('my string');
var originalString = jQueryObject.selector;// it'll give you 'my string'
```

Comment: This is what I was after, thanks. I attempted to use the selector property, but I didn't realize _how_ it worked. Thanks! Also, thanks to XwipeoutX for a similar answer.

Comment: @CJ Buchmann, consider implementing it the way that Jeremy suggests, it's a much better solution for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery(selector)`<sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)]</sup> (or `$(selector)`) is used to create a jQuery object containing elements that match the selector. Although it is possible for you to create a method which ignores the elements and retrieve the original selector, this is not efficient and makes it more difficult to understand what your code is doing.

`jQuery.trim()`<sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)]</sup> is not implemented like that. In fact, notice that `jQuery.trim()` isn't a method on a jQuery object at all! If it were, you'd invoke it like this:

```
jQuery("   foo   ").trim();
```

Instead, you do this:

```
jQuery.trim("   fooo   ");
```

`.trim()` is a method, but not a method of jQuery objects. It's a method of the jQuery constructor function itself (in some languages you would call this a "class method").

You're not creating an object and the argument is never treated as a selector. To add a function like this yourself, all you need to do is this:

```
jQuery.someFunction = function(message) { alert(message); };
```

More idiomatically, the default behaviour of the `jQuery.extend`<sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)]</sup> will do this for you:

```
jQuery.extend({someFunction: function(s) { alert(s); } })
```

That's all you need!

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well. It's not what I was looking to do, but it definitely makes sense. I wouldn't want to convolute the standard approach. I looked at the extend() function already, but I didn't connect the ability to merge objects with actually extending the functionality. I'll look into doing it this way instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
$.fn.makeLower = function() { return this.selector.toLowerCase(); }

$("FOO").makeLower(); // produces "foo"
```